# osmdroid: Who uses it for Openstreetmap map posters? pb: Gradle

Tags: android, osmdroid

A little bug. I can not integrate lib osmdroid

```
// I set Gradle (build.gradle) to integrate the osmdroid library
"dependencies {
implementation 'org.osmdroid: osmdroid-android: 6.1.2' "
```

I can not integrate lib with Sync Project for Gradle Files.

Who has already had this?

"Error: ERROR: Unable to find the method implementation () for arguments [org.osmdroid: osmdroid-android: 6.1.2] on an object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler. "

Comment: Hey, welcome to the stackoverflow. Do you have the " characters also in your gradle file? They definitely shouldn't be there. If not, remove them from your example please. Also your dependencies block doesn't' have a closing brace that would be also a problem. The error you see that you added the dependency incorrectly. I would suggest to add a bigger part of your gradle file into the question - not the whole file, but the whole part with the dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

you have to remove spaces,

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.osmdroid:osmdroid-android:6.1.2'
}
```